# I have older version xcode...was developed in mac os 10.10

Tags: ios, objective-c

previously i was done my project in xcode 6.3 and mac version msc os 10.10.now i was updated my xcode and and mac os to mac os x 10.11..Now i am facing the problem with nslayout constraints...While executing the project it was terminated automatically..Due to NSLayout Constraints...Then i was found the solution like this ...

```
 NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint     constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:0
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   relatedBy:0
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
```

Now my project was executed..But ,now am getting the problem ,previously i applied contstraints on uielements from story board are not working properly..due to that reason i cant access table view and picker view data properly..

so can any one please provide the solution to my concern..Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: What was the previous code and the reason of the complaints from XCode or the crash log? "Cant' access table view and picker view data properly" means?

Comment: That's not enough information.  What is the actual error message?